# multible-dynamic-array overflow?

Tags: asp.net, out-of-memory, dynamic-arrays

I have a question, I'm programming with asp.net

I have a multible-dynamic array

```
array_results(i, 0) = tmpdoc.Get("title")
array_results(i, 0) += tmpdoc.Get("doc_typ")    
array_results(i, 1) = tmpdoc.Get("pfad")
array_results(i, 2) = tmpdoc.Get("date_of_create")
array_results(i, 3) = tmpdoc.Get("last_change")
array_results(i, 5) = tmpdoc.Get("doc_typ")
array_results(i, 6) = CStr(score)
```

The var "i" is about 4426, I tested it with 2377 too  [Files, with information] and I get a memory exeption error.

Is it possible, that the multiple dynamic array gets an oerflow?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should look into using an `IEnumerable<T>` and do a little reading on the keywords `yield` and `yield return` and `yield break`.

Essentially using a method that returns `IEnumerable<T>` to your calling method will help prevent out-of-memory exceptions, especially when coupled with the pattern that I suggested earlier today...
[System.OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394495/system-outofmemoryexception/3394691#3394691)